# Efficiency of struct copying

Tags: c, struct, memcpy

When copying between two structure variables in C, in the back-end whether it does a memcpy or an item by item copy? Can this be compiler depended?

Comment: It's implementation dependant. But to me `memcpy` looks more efficent than item by item copy. Try with your compiler.

Comment: In fact i generally do memcpy for this case. But now I am thinking the compiler may be smart enough to do a memcpy at back. As it make no difference and is more efficient than item by item copy.

Comment: Today compilers are smart. I'd let the compiler chose. For small structs such as `struct Point {int x; int y;}` the compiler may even just emit one or two `move` instructions which is far more efficient than a call to `memcpy`.

Comment: They've always been smart and have been using a "built-in memcpy" for struct copying for a very long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's heavily compiler dependant

Consider a struct with just 2 fields

```
struct A { int a, b; };
```

Copying this struct in VS2015 in DEBUG build generates the following asm.

```
struct A b;

b = a;

mov         eax,dword ptr [a]  
mov         dword ptr [b],eax  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],ecx
```

Now added an array of 100 char and then copy that

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char x[100];
};

struct A a = { 1,2, {'1', '2'} };
struct A b;

    b = a;

mov         ecx,1Bh  
lea         esi,[a]  
lea         edi,[b]  
rep movs    dword ptr es:[edi],dword ptr [esi]
```

Now basically a memcpy is done from address of a to address of b.

It  depends on a lot of the layout of the struct, the compiler, the level of optimization...a lot of factors.

Answer (score 2):

You should not even think about that. Compilers are only required that the observable results of what they generate are the same as would you asked. Besides that, they can optimize the way they like. That means that you should let the compiler choose the way it copy structs.

The only case when the above rule does not apply it in case of low level optimization. But here other rules apply:

- never use low level optimization at early development stages
- only do after identifying by profiling the bottlenecks in your code
- always use benchmarking to choose the best way
- remember that such low level optimization only make sense for one (version of) compiler on one architecture.